# How to replace certain number of elements in array with a same element in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making a star rating component. I already filled the array with empty stars. I wanted to input a number so that when a number is entered, a certain number of stars are replaced with filled stars.

Anyway, let's take this array as an example, `[A, A, A, A, A]`. If I put in `1` rating, then the array will change to show `[B, A, A, A, A]`. If `2` ratings, then the array will be `[B, B, A, A, A]`, and so on...

I know about splice and loops but I couldn't figure out how to make it work with just the entered number and then replace it with another element. I tried to look online but no success.

Comment: You don't need to use splice. Just assign to an array element with `stars[i] = 'B';` in a loop.

Comment: [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Comment: Why do you even need an array for that? Anyway a simple `for` loop will do: `for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { arr[i] = i < numberOfStars ? "A" : "B"; }`

Comment: To all of negative comments, I'm learning javascript and I never thought about .fill() method and I'm trying to adjust my thinking from ES5 to ES6. I was looking in wrong direction because I thought .splice() was the way to go but I know that .splice wasn't the way to go in my case. So I was asking for other alternatives. So hence my "stupid" question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fill` function, passing 3 parameters, as follows.

the first you pass the letter you want to use to replace, in your example, the letter `"A"`

in the second you put the starting position, in this case the 0

and in the third, the number of times the letter `A` will repeat, according to its rating

Ex:

```js
let arr = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']

// ['B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
console.log(
  arr.fill('B', 0, 1)
)

// ['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A']
console.log(
  arr.fill('B', 0, 2)
)

//  ['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A']
console.log(
  arr.fill('B', 0, 3)
)
```

Comment: I never knew that fill can do that. I just learned this new info. I'll try this out thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could map by looking at the index.

```js
var array = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
    stars = 2;


console.log(...array);

array = array.map((v, i) => i < stars ? 'B' : v);

console.log(...array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'];
let input = 6;   //sample rating input
input = (input<=125) ? input:125; //To limit the max rating to Z
let i=0, j=0;
while(j<input){
    arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(arr[i].charCodeAt(0) + 1);  //convert char to ascii, increment by one, and convert back to char
    i++;
    j++;
    if(i===5)   i=0;
}
```